# Transform Array from Key/Value to Multi Dimensional

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

this may seem a rather trivial question, please excuse my ignorance. Still getting the hang of array manipulation...

I have a CakePHP app that is posting an array to my controller to be saved. I need to somehow reformat the sent array so that it may be processed properly by Cake's Save behaviour.

**The array posted is:**

```
Array ( 
        [788] => Array ( [id] => 788 )  
        [787] => Array ( [id] => 787 )  
        [786] => Array ( [id] => 0 )  
        [785] => Array ( [id] => 0 )  

        [value_1] => 0 

        [analysed_date] => Array ( 
           [month] => 08 
           [day] => 16 
           [year] => 2011 
        )  

        [job_id] => 34 
)
```

**Desired Array:**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 788 
        [value_1] => 0 
        [analysed_date] => Array ( 
            [month] => 08 
            [day] => 16 
            [year] => 2011 
        )  
    )  
    [1] => Array ( 
        [id] => 787 
        [value_1] => 0 
        [analysed_date] => Array ( 
            [month] => 08 
            [day] => 16 
            [year] => 2011 
        )  
    )  
)
```

Thanks for taking the time to look.

---

**EDIT:**

I've just realised I omitted the fact that if the array has an [id] => 0 that it needs to be ignored. This was my primary stumbling block. Apologies. I hope the edit clarifies my problem better.

**SOLVED**

Thank you for your help guys. I was able to come up with the solution by myself. Here is what I came up with.

```
foreach($org_array as $key => $value){
    if(is_array($value)){
        if(isset($value['id'])){
            if($value['id'] != 0) {
                $data[$i] = array(
                    'id' => $value['id'],
                    'value_1'=> $value_1,
                    'analysed_date' => $date
                );
                $i++;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, but just for your example:

```
$array_keys = array_keys($org_array);
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array_keys as $key)
{
  if (is_int($key))
  {
    $new_array[] = array(
        "id" => $key,
        "value1" => $org_array["value1"],
        "analysed_date" => $org_array["analysed_date"]
      );
    // you might want to loop throught the original array to get all non-integer key values instead of hard-coding it
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$main = Array ( 
        [788] => Array ( [id] => 788 )  
        [787] => Array ( [id] => 787 )  
        [786] => Array ( [id] => 786 )  
        [785] => Array ( [id] => 785 )  

        [value_1] => 0 

        [analysed_date] => Array ( 
           [month] => 08 
           [day] => 16 
           [year] => 2011 
        )  

        [job_id] => 34 
) 

$analysed_date = $main['analysed_date'];
$value1 = $main['value_1'];

$result = array();
$i=0;
foreach($main as $key=>$value)
{
if( is_numeric($key)
 {
   $result[$i]=array();
   $result[$i]['id']=$key;
   $result[$i]['value_1']=$value1;
   $result[$i]['analysed_date']=$analysed_date;
   $i++;
 }
}
```